# Is there a suffix that means "like", or "resembling"?

Tags: noun, suffixes

What would be the appropriate suffix to add to a word to say that it resembles the noun? In English, we have the example of "Roguelike" (or Rogue-like), which is a style of video game. It's a substantive that tells you the game is like a particular style of gameplay.

For a Latin example, say there's a thing that resembles a rock and you want to say it's rock-like. Could you add *-similis* to *saxum* to have something like *saxisimilis*? Is there a better suffix or another way to express this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Despite *verisimilis* (which Lewis and Short note should be separated), I would instead recommend going the Greek route using [-ειδής](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-oid?ref=etymonline_crossreference) suffix. This means "in the shape or form of" and can be used for things that are similar to but distinct from the original object.

Two examples:

- ἀνηθοειδής "like dill" (not dill, but similar to it)
- ἑλικοειδής "in the shape of a spiral"

I don't believe it's a productive suffix in Latin, but theoretically you could generate a learned coinage like κλεπτοειδής (*cleptoides*, 'like a thief') with it. Beware, though, [κακοειδής](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dkakoeidh%2Fs) (*cacoides*, 'like a bad person/thing') is already a word, though since it's a hapax legomenon, it should be easy to borrow with a slightly different meaning.

You can translate Rogue-like, though, since Rogue is a proper noun (i.e. Rogue-likes are games in the gameplay style of Rogue).

Fortunately for your other example we *do* have a Greek word for "rock-like": [λιθοειδής](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dliqoeidh%2Fs). It's also safely attested, found in Plato of all people (and a couple other places). It would be Latinized into *lithoides* (which doubles as a scientific Latin name given to a species of [catfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithoxus_lithoides), among other species).

Answer (score 8):

**Appendicitis** is an inflammation of the *processus vermiformis*, the appendix in the shape of a worm.

A search for words that end in *-formis* in L&S yields 20 results. Some of these have numbers: *biformis*, *quadriformis*, *septiformis*, *multiformis*.

There are two that actually translate to *having the form of ...*:

> *caniformis* (having the form of a dog)

> *tauriformis* (bullshaped).

Strangely, *vermiformis* is not among them.

By analogy, *in the form of a rock* might be *saxiformis*, but I have only found this on [marinespecies.org](https://marinespecies.org/traits/aphia.php?p=taxdetails&id=1481544).